# How can we create Variables in LogDNA?

Tags: ibm-cloud, logdna

In LogDNA we have many rows like this:

> {"message":"bend.eu-de.mybluemix.net - [2019-07-22T09:25:43.834+0000] \"POST /api/public/disco HTTP/1.1\" 200 91 1713 \"-\" \"Apache-CXF/3.1.18\" \"10.100.29.195:37516\" \"160.00.23.107:61186\" x_forwarded_for:\"10.208.176.114,203.201.183.198, 20.105.29.195\" x_forwarded_proto:\"https\" vcap_request_id:\"8800770-2007-4684-7791-ef5eab043c\" response_time:0.506587776 app_id:\"4736d7ea-f2c8-48b4-87e2-ce0cfaee40\" app_index:\"0\" x_global_transaction_id:\"06a17600003580701924e91\" true_client_ip:\"-\" x_b3_traceid:\"0e360106751\" x_b3_spanid:\"0e0870106751\" x_b3_parentspanid:\"-\" b3:\"0e0006751-0e006751\"\n"}

Is it possible to define a variable on **response_time** ?
an can we use this variable in a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within settings you can go to "parsing" .. if you need help, visit this webinar, which is very helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1e_7x3KQko
regards
Leo